# How to use Kotlin String Templates in Room Migration statements

Tags: android, kotlin, android-sqlite, android-room

I am attempting to create a Room Migration as follows:-

```
class Migration_1_2(startVersion: Int = 1, endVersion: Int = 2) : Migration(startVersion, endVersion) {

    override fun migrate(database: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {

        database.execSQL(CREATE_TEMP_MY_TABLE_TABLE)
        database.execSQL(COPY_MY_TABLE)
        database.execSQL(DROP_MY_TABLE_TABLE)
        database.execSQL(ALTER_TEMP_MY_TABLE_TABLE)

    }

    companion object {

        private const val NEW_COLUMN_A_EMPTY = " "
        private const val NEW_COLUMN_B_EMPTY = " "
        private const val NEW_COLUMN_C_EMPTY = " "
        private const val NEW_COLUMN_D_EMPTY = " "        

        private const val CREATE_TEMP_MY_TABLE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE 'temp_myTable' ('column_one' TEXT, 'column_two' TEXT, 'column_three' TEXT, 'column_four' TEXT, 'uuid' TEXT NOT NULL, 'new_column_a' TEXT, 'column_five' TEXT, 'column_six' TEXT, 'new_column_b' TEXT, 'new_column_c' TEXT, 'new_column_d' TEXT, 'new_column_e' TEXT, PRIMARY KEY('uuid'))"
        private const val COPY_MY_TABLE = "INSERT INTO temp_myTable SELECT column_one, column_two, column_three, column_four, uuid, $NEW_COLUMN_A_EMPTY, column_five, column_six, $NEW_COLUMN_B_EMPTY, $NEW_COLUMN_C_EMPTY, $NEW_COLUMN_D_EMPTY, $NEW_COLUMN_E_EMPTY FROM myTable"
        private const val DROP_MY_TABLE_TABLE = "DROP TABLE 'myTable'"
        private const val ALTER_TEMP_MY_TABLE_TABLE = "ALTER TABLE 'temp_myTable' RENAME TO 'myTable'"

    }
}
```

using `NEW_COULMN_#_EMPTY` string constants instead of "`' '`" to document which column is being set to `BLANK`.

This code does compile even though Android Studio reports `<result column> expected, got ','`

I guess this is `Room` not liking `Kotlin` string templates

IS there any way I can employ `Kotlin` string templates in my sqlite raw SQL?

Comment: You need to used Kotlin variables in the String template right? You can do this via "${variable}" This will replace with the variable value in the string.

Comment: basically what you are doing is inserting and extra space in the sql query. Wouldn't it be automatically removed.? Could you try changing(add an extra ' inside the " ") -> private const val NEW_COLUMN_#_EMPTY = "' '"

Comment: @AkhilSoman thanks for spotting this, an embarrassing error on my part :(